# Organic group request membership email issue

Tags: organic-groups, emails, notifications

Can anyone recommend how I can get an emailing system working for when users request to join an organic group on my system?

Right now, my users click the "request membership" links and then provides a message and click a join button. But then nothing else happens.

Neighter the user nor the admin get any email confirmation.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

For OG 7.x-1.x, I discovered that simply by enabling the Rules module, email notification Rules from OG are made active. That did the trick for me.

(Not sure about OG 7.x-2.x, which makes mention of the Message_Notify module on the OG project page...)

Comment: I have OG 7.x-2.x and Rules enabled, and I don't get the email notifications. In what order did you activate them? What other modules do you have activated?

Comment: Oh stupid me, it's the same for 7.x-2.x. It's just that the rules are disabled by default, so you need to go to the Rules configuration and enable them, that's it.